# Redstone torch, repeater, comparator help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to make a simple chest shop casino by tutorial on YouTube ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0XMIbAAp1o)). Everything went well it's really simple but I'm struggling with one thing that is happening to me. Look at screenshots.

At the first image the redstone torch is on, the repeater is powered and I need it to be like in second image where the redstone torch is off and the comparator is powered. How to do that? I made 3 slots so far. First one without problem, second one had the same problem but I don't really know how I solved it and with this one I can't do anything. Any ideas what's wrong? I did everything same.

[image: Redstone torch on]

[image: Redstone torch off]

Comment: It would be more useful, if you recreate screenshots with default texturepack (and maybe more light)

Comment: Could you add a description of what you want this to do? (ie. I want the hopper to be unpowered for 2 seconds whenever someone puts something in the chest)

Comment: Hello, i was trying to make this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0XMIbAAp1o

Answer (score 1):

Are the two screenshots supposed to be of the same design? If so, it appears as though the top screenshot has the torch, repeater, and comparator 1 block too far from the camera. Move those items 1 block towards the camera, and that might solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, actually i didnt noticed that thanks i figured i have that problem of many of my machines. I fixed them most of them are working but when Im buildinh new one (im following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0XMIbAAp1o ) i still have problem that repeater is powered (or glowing) instead of comparator.

Comment: @DocMattes there needs to be exactly one item in the chest, and many in the lower dropper